# Replace characters in a column with numbers R

Tags: r, replace, label

I have a matrix with last column contains characters:

```
A
B
B
A
...
```

I would like to replace A with 1 and B with 2 in R. The expected result should be:

```
1
2
2
1
...
```

Comment: `as.numeric(factor(...))`? See also `match`, perhaps?

Comment: `as.numeric(chartr("AB", "12", c("A", "B", "B", "A")))`

Comment: @RichScriven: This is the best and more general answer and exactly what I was looking for. What if you have an array of strings with different length, or want to substitute A and B to 1 and C and D to 2? The factors won't work. So, this solution worths a separate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are 100% confident only `"A"` and `"B"` appear

```
sample_data = c("A", "B", "B", "A")
sample_data
# [1] "A" "B" "B" "A"
as.numeric(gsub("A", 1, gsub("B", 2, sample_data)))
# [1] 1 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `factor` or a simple lookup table would be much more flexible:

```
sample_data = c("A", "B", "B", "A")
```

Recommended:

```
as.numeric(factor(sample_data))
# [1] 1 2 2 1
```

Possible alternative:

```
as.numeric(c("A" = "1", "B" = "2")[sample_data])
# [1] 1 2 2 1
```

Comment: This will not in general work as the ordering of the levels of the factor is not necessarily the order they appear in the data. A more robust approach is `as.integer(forcat::fct_inorder(sample_data))` if this ordering is necessary.